# Can mockito or easymock replace rmock

Tags: easymock, mockito

I'm sitting with a legacy project, and we're starting to replace some old legacycode. As Rmock don't have support for junit4, we would like to replace it. One thing i was wondering is - how could i replace the dynamictestsuite feature of rmock. This is a good feature where you create a dynamic testsuite for each run, and can do stuff like.

```
@Override
protected void setupSuite() {
        forEach(is.clazz.assignableTo(TestCase.class).and(is.not(is.clazz.name(is.endingWith("oldTest")))).perform(addAllToSuite);

}
```

that would get all testclasses not ending with oldTest and create a dynamictestsuite. And so on, you get the point.

Comment: I think the title of your question doesn't match the content. If you make the title a bit less generic that would be better imo.

Answer (score 1):

[ClasspathSuite](http://www.johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp) can define a suite by searching for JUnit test classes in the class path, with a filter on the test class names to include or exclude.

```
import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@ClassnameFilters({"!.*oldTest"})
public class MySuite {}
```